# Adding more than one LinearLayout into scrollview using while loop

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to add more than one LinearLayout into my ScrollView, the number of LinearLayout is base on how many data selected from the MySQL database. However, it seems can't add more than one LinearLayout into the ScrollView.

The reason is maybe this: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. But I am not sure about the real reason. How can I solve this problem? Here is my coding in Android Studio:

```
String query = "select * from restaurant";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

LinearLayout data_big_layout, detail_data_layout;
TextView name, type_area, price_txt;
ImageView restaurant_img;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams restaurant_img_params, data_big_params;

while(rs.next()){
    data_big_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    data_big_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    data_big_params.setMargins(0,15,0,0);
    data_big_layout.setLayoutParams(data_big_params);
    data_big_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    data_big_layout.setWeightSum(20);
    data_big_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    data_big_layout.setTag(rs.getInt(1));

    detail_data_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,8.0f);
    detail_data_layout.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    detail_data_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    detail_data_layout.setPadding(50,0,0,0);

    lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    name = new TextView(this);
    name.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    name.setText(rs.getString(2));
    name.setTextSize(24);
    name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    type_area = new TextView(this);
    type_area.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    type_area.setText(rs.getString(5)+"/"+rs.getString(6));
    type_area.setTextSize(18);

    price_txt = new TextView(this);
    price_txt.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    price_txt.setText(rs.getString(7));
    price_txt.setTextSize(18);

    detail_data_layout.addView(name);
    detail_data_layout.addView(type_area);
    detail_data_layout.addView(price_txt);

    data_big_layout.addView(detail_data_layout);

    restaurant_img = new ImageView(this);
    restaurant_img_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,
    300,12.0f);
    restaurant_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_restaurant);
    restaurant_img.setPadding(0,0,50,0);

    data_big_layout.addView(restaurant_img, restaurant_img_params);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ID: "+rs.getInt(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    data_scroll_view.addView(data_big_layout); //Cannot add data_big_layout in the next loop

    z = "Search successful";

}
isSuccess = true;
stmt.close();
rs.close();
con.close();
```

The code **data_scroll_view.addView(data_big_layout);** only can run in the first time of the while loop. I selected two rows of data but the output in programme only can show one LinearLayout. How can I solve it? Thanks all.

Comment: ScrollView only accept one child. You can put a LinearLayout inside the ScrollView as parent then put your layouts inside that layout as child

Comment: How can I identify which layout I click using this way. All the valuables are the last selected data of the database, I have no ways to identify which one I click.

Answer (score 1):

scroll view can only contain one child

> Scroll view may have only one direct child placed within it. [Google doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView)

therefore, inside your loop, you should gather your views into a single vertical LinearLayout then add it to the ScrollView outside of the loop.

Comment: I solved the problem with changed the scrollview to another linearlayout, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView

> ScrollView is "A view group that allows the view hierarchy placed
>   within it to be scrolled. Scroll view may have only one direct child
>   placed within it.

To add multiple views within the scroll view, make the direct child you add a view group, for example `LinearLayout`, and place additional views within that `LinearLayout`".

So instead of trying to add `LinearLayouts` to the `ScrollView`, put one `LinearLayout` as the `ScrollView's` child and add any views/layouts to that `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I solved the problem with changed the scrollview to another linearlayout, thank you!